# How can I keep a number as root out of x

Tags: python, math, geometry

So my code looks like this , with comments :

```
import math


#I want to do this : If the figure is a triangle it's side , noted with l = r(Stands for radius) square root 3 
#another thing(Which I don't know how to spell in english) , noted with a = r/2 , it's area based on the side(noted with Al)
# = (l**2*Square root of 3) / 4 and it's area based on the radius = (3r**2*Square root of 3)/4

#My problem is that I want to keep the square root of 3 as a number without .07214214312412etc. and if it isn't a perfect
#square keep it like root3 , or something like that if it's possible

figure = input("What is the figure?")
figure = figure.lower()
r = int(input("What is the radius?"))
if figure == "triangle" :
    l = str(r) + " Square root of 3"
    a = int(r) / 2
    l = float(l)
    Al = str((l**2/4)) + " Square root of 3"
    Ar = str(3*r**2/4) + " Square root of 3"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its absurd to take `float()` of the string `" Square root of 3"`. I guess you are trying to use the square root sign, then i think you have to use the sympy library, and your code follows

```
from sympy import *
figure = input("What is the figure?")
figure = figure.lower()
r = int(input("What is the radius?"))
x=sqrt(3)
if figure == "triangle" :
    l=r*x
    a = float(r) / 2
    Al = (l**2/4)*x
    Ar = (3*r**2/4)*x
```

also if you want to use it as string, as you did in your code you can use like this

```
from math import *
figure = input("What is the figure?")
figure = figure.lower()
r = int(input("What is the radius?"))
x="*sqrt(3)"
if figure == "triangle" :
    l=str(r)+x
    a = float(r) / 2
    Al = str(eval(l)**2/4)+x
    Ar = str(3*r**2/4)+x
```

Comment: here l is a string so you cant just square it. the eval function takes the string and execute it as a normal python code. read more about eval and exec funtions.

Answer (score 0):

I may be confused about what you're getting at here -- are you saying you just want to do basically

```
root3 = math.sqrt(3)
```

or something else?